# How is treasure determined randomly for CR 21 or higher creatures?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, encounter-design, treasure, wealth

The *Magic Item Compendium* says

> **Step 1:** Roll on Table A-1: Treasure, using the monster's CR to determine which row you will use. (265)

Table A-1: Treasure only goes to Challenge Rating 20. The six level-17-plus PCs in my campaign have begun encountering CR 21+ creatures. How can I continue to use random treasure from the *Magic Item Compendium* to reward the PCs appropriately?

Comment: I'd really really like to see an answer that actually *expands the tables*, even if it's just something extrapolated from the existing data.

Answer (score 4):

There is an Epic Level Handbook that can be used for adventures over 20th level.

It gives you treasure value and exp and such for encounters above CR 21. It looks like for treasure it sticks to purely value of worth.(GP) Rather than actual items, since Epic magic items are worth alot more than the normal items.

Also, the Dungeon Masters Guide Gives you additional tables and rules for up to 30th level.

I cant copy and paste specifics, but the DMG has info around page 52 and the Epic book had stuff around page 121ish.

**EDIT**(As suggested by comments below)
*The epic level book is a bit more precise, by just using the total treasure value. The DMG simply suggests adding more magic items per CR. The Compendium specifically talks about replacing the random tables in the DMG with these, so I would even go so far as to suggest the expanded CR table in the DMG(on the bottom of page 52) is the "proper" course of action.*

Comment: To be clear, despite wanting to stick with the *Magic Item Compendium*, you recommend that I either switch to the rules in the *Epic Level Handbook* or use the major magic items rules for Treasure on 51-6 from the *DMG*?

Comment: Well, they are all 3.5 rule set. The compendium just gives you a larger variety in magic items from what I remember. The epic level book is a bit more precise, by just using the total treasure value. The DMG simply suggests adding more magic items per CR. The Compendium specifically talks about replacing the random tables in the DMG with these, so I would even go so far as to suggest the expanded CR table in the DMG(on the bottom of page 52) is the "proper" course of action.

Comment: @MikeR, your last comment has a more "generic" approach than your answer. I.e. it clearly states guidelines and could easily be mixed-and-matched with the _Magic item compendium_; which is what I believe the OP wants. Maybe you could complement your answer with your comment?

Comment: @Roflo Thought about it myself, good suggestion, so its done. :)